# How can I customize the mysqldump command for a large table in my backup?

Tags: mysql-backup

When restoring my mysql backup I get an error message: Row size too large.

Can I customize the mysqldump command?

My backup command is

`mysqldump -u $db_name -p'$db_passwd' --quick --allow-keywords --add-drop-table --complete-insert --quote-names $db_name >$sql_file`

The relevant line is

`CREATE TABLE kreisfreie_gliederung( Bundeslandint(2) DEFAULT NULL, bundesland_destatisint(2) NOT NULL, koordinatenvarchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL, LKint(4) NOT NULL, landkreis_destatisint(4) NOT NULL, Reihenfolgeint(3) DEFAULT NULL, LKNamevarchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, kreisfreivarchar(1) DEFAULT NULL, LKM1varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM2varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM3varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM4varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM5varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM6varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM7varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM8varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM9varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM10varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM11varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM12varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM13varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM14varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM15varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM16varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM17varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM18varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM19varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM20varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM21varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM22varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM23varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM24varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM25varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM26varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM27varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM28varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM29varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM30varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM31varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM32varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM33varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM34varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM35varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM36varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM37varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM38varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM39varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM40varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM41varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM42varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM43varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM44varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM45varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM46varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM47varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM48varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM49varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM50varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM51varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM52varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM53varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM54varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM55varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM56varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM57varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM58varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM59varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM60varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM61varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM62varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM63varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM64varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM65varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM66varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM67varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM68varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM69varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM70varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM71varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM72varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM73varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM74varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM75varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM76varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM77varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM78varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM79varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM80varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM81varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM82varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM83varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM84varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM85varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM86varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM87varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM88varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM89varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM90varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM91varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM92varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM93varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM94varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM95varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM96varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM97varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM98varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM99varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM100varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM101varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM102varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM103varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM104varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM105varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM106varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM107varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM108varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM109varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM110varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM111varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM112varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM113varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM114varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM115varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM116varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM117varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM118varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM119varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM120varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM121varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM122varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM123varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM124varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM125varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM126varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM127varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM128varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM129varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM130varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM131varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM132varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM133varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM134varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM135varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM136varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM137varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM138varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM139varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM140varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM141varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM142varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM143varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM144varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM145varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM146varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM147varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM148varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM149varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM150varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM151varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM152varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM153varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM154varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM155varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM156varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM157varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM158varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM159varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM160varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM161varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM162varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM163varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM164varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM165varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM166varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM167varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM168varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM169varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM170varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM171varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM172varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM173varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM174varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM175varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM176varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM177varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM178varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM179varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM180varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM181varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM182varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM183varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM184varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM185varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM186varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM187varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM188varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM189varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM190varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM191varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM192varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM193varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM194varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM195varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM196varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM197varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM198varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM199varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM200varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM201varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM202varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM203varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM204varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM205varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM206varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM207varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM208varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM209varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM210varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM211varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM212varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM213varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM214varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM215varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM216varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM217varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM218varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM219varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM220varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM221varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM222varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM223varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM224varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM225varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM226varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM227varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM228varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM229varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM230varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM231varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM232varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM233varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM234varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM235varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM236varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM237varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM238varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM239varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM240varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM241varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM242varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM243varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM244varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, LKM245 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (LK)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;`